# I am learning electricity and magnetism remotely, what is the best tool kit in the market for a home lab to accompany this college course?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education, software

My university suspended all labs in the physics department and there is no virtual option, but for me to understand E&M I need to see some live experiments and do them myself. What lab kit on the market can help me understand concepts like Gauss' Law, electric potential and the mathematical justifications for the electric field of a wire, non-conducting sphere and conducting hollow cylinder? What equipment would I need to measure electric field? This is a calculus based class for freshmen/sophomores and we are supposed to have a 3 hour lab every week.

Right now my E&M just feels like a math class but there is no physical intuition as to why anything is true other than to treat them as ideas that should reflect reality.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer this question without knowing more about your syllabus. Also availability of kits may depend on your location. I suggest you ask for university for a list of lab experiments (with instructions, if possible) and the equipment you would need to carry out these experiments at home. And remember some experiments may fall into the "do not try this at home" category because they are not safe outside of a laboratory environment.

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant that you are trying to focus on intuitive understanding.
Umm well lab kits is a brilliant option as well- I'd like to tell you but that there are many, many online **simulation** tools available - For example, you can FEEL the triboelectric effect through the online simulators available, and so on.

You can search for simulators and animations online, see https://www.physicsclassroom.com/mmedia/estatics/itsn.cfm, etc.

Many top universities like UCLA and University of Wisconsin even have their course materials online.